# Draggable Point

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, draggable, dynamic-data-display

I am working with a chart in wpf with dynamic data display. I would like to insert a dynamic draggable point. Until now I can just insert one like this

```
<d3:DraggablePoint Position="0.2,0.2" />
```

but I would like to insert it behind the code, unfortunately I dont see how! I can just modify some of its properties as soon as I give a name in the project map and just modify this specific element.

Can anyone point me how to do a draggable point by myself so that when the chart zooms or pads, the point also do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to include the using statement:

```
using Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.Charts.Shapes;
```

Then instantiate your DraggablePoint like :

```
DraggablePoint dPoint = new DraggablePoint();
```

Set up your DraggablePoint properties, then add it to your plot like :

```
plotter.Children.Add(dPoint);
```